# SQLite CreateTable with Class<T> without specific T

Tags: c#, sqlite

How can I use CreateTable with an class like `class Cache<T> {}` 
When I type `CreateTable<Cache>();` I have got an error saying that using generic Cache require on argument.

But the purpose of this class is to handle multiple objet type and save them into the same table. T is requested for Cache methods that return Type to match to the attempted return type.

How can i handle this?

Comment: If you want to handle unknown types you either need to use `object`, `dynamic`, or reflection if you know the type at runtime.

Comment: Have you tried `CreateTable<Cache<object>>();`?

Comment: Uhm ... if he creates a table based on object, how is he supposed to save any data?

Comment: Manfred is right, I can't use type in table, the purpose of this table is to get all object cached in, whatever type they are. I have got in Cache class a method that retrieved them by the field ObjectType that i set when i save them in Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for what it worse, I got my answer.
I created an interface with all fields from Cache class.
I used this interface with the CreateTable method and voilà!

At least for the creation, but for retrieving object I need to specified the type like Cache or Cache.
This is not a big deal just passing the right type to Cache by using `typeof ( T ).FullName`

It is the cache class that handle restoration from DB